# grep for single quote and double quote in a string

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am trying to write a grep which finds the .epl file names or file paths in a given file.

I have tried the following regexs

Part 1 : REGEX Used grep -rEco "/(.+).epl|(.+).epl" ./index.epl Result obtained

```
url => 'xyz.epl
url => 'xyz.epl
url => 'xyz.epl
url => "packet/xyz.epl
url => "/web/abc/xyz.epl
url => qq{/web/abc/xyz.epl
url => '/web/abc/def/xyz.epl
url => '/web/abc/def/xyz.epl
url => 'xyz.epl
url => 'xyz.epl
$url = "/web/abc/def/xyz.epl
var requestURL = "xyz.epl
var requestURL = "xyz.epl
<a style="float:left;" href="xyz.epl
[- Execute('components/xyz.epl
Welcome, <a href="xyz.epl
[- Execute('components/xyz.epl
<a href="xyz.epl
[- Execute(`'components/xyz.epl`
```

However I want it to match only the following (with or without the preceding quotes)

```
'xyz.epl(OR xyz.epl)
'xyz.epl
'xyz.epl
"packet/xyz.epl(OR packet/xyz.epl)
"/web/abc/xyz.epl(OR "/web/abc/xyz.epl)
/web/abc/xyz.epl
'/web/abc/def/xyz.epl
'/web/abc/def/xyz.epl
'xyz.epl
'xyz.epl
"/web/abc/def/xyz.epl
"xyz.epl
"xyz.epl
"xyz.epl
'components/xyz.epl
"xyz.epl
'components/xyz.epl
"xyz.epl
'components/xyz.epl
```

To obtain the desired out I tried `grep -rEoc '\/(.+)\.epl|[\"\'](.+)\.epl'` However it gives me an "unmatched '." error.

I removed the quotes surrounding the regex and I got "Badly placed ()'s."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your sample input, this produced your desired output:

```
grep -Eo '["'\'']?[/[:alnum:]]+\.epl'
```

It makes some assumptions about the characters in your filenames (letters, numbers, slashes) -- feel free to throw more characters into that set of brackets.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will do it for you:

```
grep -oP "(?<=['\"]|qq{)[xp/c][^\`]+" ./index.epl
```

This says:

`-o` Only keep the matching part.
`-P` Use Perl style regex (we need this for the lookbehind)
`"..."` Use double quotes since you can't escape the single within single
`(?<=...)` Start a positive lookbehind group. This means that whatever we match much also have this pattern right before it, but the "before part" isn't part of the pattern we want to keep.
`[\'\"]` Match one of: single or double quote
`|qq{` OR match the literal string 'qq{'
Once you find that pattern match:
`[xp/c]` Match one of x, p, /, or c. (This is not so nice but you have a small number of cases to check.)
`[^`]+` Anything that's not a backtick, 1 or more times

**EDIT:** If you want the single or double quotes to be part of the pattern it will be a little more tricky since you don't seem to want the `qq{` to be included either way.

Comment: You are correct. The escape was a typo. I don't know a good way to get the last quote (i tried look ahead but couldn't get it to work). The single matching char after the ' or " will do it but it's not very regexy. Do you have a suggestion I'm missing?

Comment: Not any good suggestions at the moment. Have only glimpsed at it and doubt I'll look at it now as it is "answered" :P